# Creating a very simple toolbox with jquery. How to insert text from title attr

Tags: jquery, toolbox

I'm about to create a very simple tooltip solution for my website based on jquery.
Im using the following script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$("a.tooltip").hover(function () {
    $('<div class="tooltip-box"><p></p></div>').text($this.attr('title')).appendTo(this);
    }, function () {
    $("div.tooltip-box").remove();
});
$("a.tooltip").on("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

});

The markup:

```
<a href="#" title="Tooltip text here" class="tooltip"></a>
```

Somehow it isn't working at the moment. I tried a lot myself and searched here but can't figure it out.
Sorry if is only simple syntax error. I'm a jquery beginner.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that `$('<div class="tooltip-box"><p></p></div>')` is a valid jQuery selector (I could be wrong).

I would recommend *not* trying to always get everything on one line. Try something like this (untested):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$("a.tooltip").hover(function () {
    var titleText=$(this).attr("title");
    $(this).after("<div id='tooltip-box'>" +titleText+ "</div>");
    }, function () {
    $("div#tooltip-box").remove();
});
$("a.tooltip").on("click", function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});
});
```

[Here is a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VK9Rz/).

You will of course need to style the div with your own CSS.

Good luck!

Comment: Perfect thank you! I'm so new to jquery I actually wanted to do it by defining a variable first but failed because I didn't know how to embed the var in the append. It's working now! Just so that I learn something here: the correct way to define a variable in jquery is the way you did it and just like in javascript? I read somewhere that this is not valid... Thanks again :) my first post here and problem solved within 5min. Exciting!

Comment: jQuery is not a different language, it is just a library. Any javascript functions, variables, syntax, etc still work fine. When using jQuery you will usually run into some more advanced variables (complex objects and DOM's) - but the simple stuff still works fine too.

Answer (score 0):

I've taken your code and just modified something. Here it is working. I've put some text in your

tag to identify if the right tag is in effect.

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

$('a').hover(function(){
    $('.tooltip-box p').text('test');
}, 
             function () {
    $("div.tooltip-box p").text('this will change');        
});

$("a.tooltip").on("click", function(event){
event.preventDefault();
});
```

});

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" title="Tooltip text here" class="tooltip">click</a>
<div class="tooltip-box">
    <p>this will change</p>
</div>
```

This is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arifulhb/Ky5mw/)

Best of Luck.